# ASP 3.0 MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 and restful method with optional parameter

Tags: .net, wcf, vbscript, asp-classic

We have a restful web app written in .NET (4.6.1), that has the following UriTemplate:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetAssociationLevelCustomerData/{environment}/{AssetKeyFilter=-1}/{UsersTZOffset=0}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

public PLEGatewayCore.Entities.M2MDB.DSPAssociationItem    GetAssociationLevelCustomerItem(string environment, String AssetKeyFilter, string UsersTZOffset)
```

We then have a classic ASP (3.0) (VbScript) app trying to get the data from it with the following mechanism:

```
Sub ExecuteWebRequest(strMethod, url, data, intStatus, strResponse)
Dim webRequest
'On Error Resume Next
Set webRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  intStatus = -1
  strResponse = "(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
      Else
  With webRequest
    .Open strMethod, url, false
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", Session("ses_APIToken")
    .SetRequestHeader "Ver", "3.0"
    .SetRequestHeader "SourceId", "3"
    IF strMethod = "POST" THEN
        .Send data
    ELSE
        .Send
    END IF

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      intStatus = -1
      strResponse = "(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
    Else
      intStatus = .Status
      strResponse = "(" & .Status & ") " & .StatusText
      If .Status = "200" Then strResponse = .ResponseText End If
    End if
   End With
End If

Set webRequest = Nothing

'Exit Sub
```

End Sub

Examples:

```
https://<url>/GetAssociationLevelCustomerData/PROD/6108213631162262528/4
```

works

```
https://<url>/GetAssociationLevelCustomerData/PROD/6108213631162262528
```

does not work

What we are noticing is, if we leave off an optional/defaulted parameter like "UsersTZOffset", then the request will fail.  If we run the url from PostMan we have no issues.  What might cause this behavior?  Is it something to do with the XMLHttp.6.0 object, or something in the restful api endpoint, or something else entirely?

Comment: There is nothing “RESTful” about that API architecture, it’s more an RPC style API.

Comment: You want to compare both the postman request with the Classic ASP one with something like Fiddler to see what the difference is. At the moment you are making an assumption about the optional parameter being the cause, it’s more likely a difference in the HTTP headers being sent.